# Crystal Report Next after a page break

Tags: crystal-reports, page-break

I need to print some rows in natural order. In some case, i need to print all rows, in other to cumulate some rows, if repetitive.
I use some variables, placed in the detail row (first and last omitted):

```
{@aggitot}
shared numbervar tqtaprezzo;
tqtaprezzo:=tqtaprezzo+{RIGHEDOCUMENTI.QTAGEST};

{@mostraqtaprezzo}
evaluateafter({@aggitot});
shared numbervar tqtaprezzo;
if {EXTRACLIENTI.DettaglioLotti}='SI' then
    {RIGHEDOCUMENTI.QTAGEST}
else
    tqtaprezzo

{@aggitot2}
evaluateafter({@mostraqtaprezzo});
shared numbervar tqtaprezzo;
if {RIGHEDOCUMENTI.CODART}<>next({RIGHEDOCUMENTI.CODART}) then
    tqtaprezzo:=0
```

And this condition on the detail omit section

```
{RIGHEDOCUMENTI.CODART}=next({RIGHEDOCUMENTI.CODART} and {EXTRACLIENTI.DettaglioLotti}<>'SI'
```

The reports seems OK, but when DettaglioLotti='SI' and immediately after each page break the first row printed shows only one record, and not two or more.

Any idea?

Comment: You are using one shared variable across many formulas...first question is where are those formulas placed and you are suppressing some data in details which has exact opposite of one of the formulas....how your data looks like and what do you want to display

Comment: All variables are in the same detail row, mostraqtaprezzo in the center, aggitot and aggitot2 near the right border. The objective was to show all rows when DettaglioLotti='SI' and a cumulative row, but only when two or more consecutive rows are identical when DettaglioLotti<>'SI'. I have to respect the natural order in the original data so I cannot use simple group function

Comment: Sorry still I am confused... may be I am unable to understand your requrirement... but one though is for testing purpose remove all formulas and just place database fields and test your section condition that way you will be able to trace out the issue